# In a /etc/init/script how I capture event for "eth1 is ready" on RHEL 6 in upstarts?

Tags: upstart, nic, rhel6

I've tried below, but doesn't work:

1:start on (net-device-up IFACE!=lo and runlevel [2345])

2:start on started network-interface INTERFACE=eth1

I saw the networking service is still be brought up by calling these init.d scripts,
so I doubt on RHEL 6, there is real a "event" from upstart for NIC's up.

anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out somehow by:
    start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL [2345]

so the upstart job rc(/etc/init/rc.conf) just call all the init scripts by 
    exec /etc/rc.d/rc $RUNLEVEL

when all the rc scripts done, all the NIC are up, and the job "rc" in upstarts does have a status change and emit status.